# Adding a javascript tag only in mobile devices

Tags: javascript, mobile

I need a little help with getting my javascript code to run only in mobile devices.  I did some simple research and found this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   if($(window).width() <= 480){
    // do your stuff
   }
</script>
```

but when I implement it with my code, its not working right.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if($(window).width() <= 480){
    name='container' src='https://example.com/embeds/java.js'
   }
</script>
```

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Yeah, that is a JavaScript error. If you want to add a file, append ir or document.write it.

Comment: Any idea how to fix it?  I basically just want to run another javascript code if the window width is smaller than 480px.

Comment: Either document.write() it or createElement and appendChild()

Answer (score 1):

you also have to check height to get exact device dimensions

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var width = $(window).width(), height = $(window).height();
    if ((width <= 1023) && (height >= 768)) {
      //do some stuff
    }
</script>
```